# How to create a PATCH file for the binary difference output file

Tags: binary, diff, patch

I want to know how to create a PATCH for the difference file I got by comparing two binary files. 
$cmp -l   > output file name

I checked for text files 'diff" can be used to compare and generate a PATCH file 
$ diff -u oldFile newFile > mods.diff  # -u tells diff to output unified diff format

I want to apply the PATCH on the old binary image file to get my new binary image file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary diff tool for very large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool-for-very-large-files)

Comment: @EvanCarroll the page you have mentioned is might be removed.

Answer (score 10):

Diff and Patch are designed to work with text files, not arbitrary binary data.  You should use something like [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

**If** your repository, or package **is using git** you can make binary diff with
`git diff --patch --binary old_dir patched_dir`

Of course you can also use it with commits
`git diff --patch --binary commit1 commit2`

Answer (score 3):

[JDIFF](http://jojodiff.sourceforge.net/) is a program that outputs the differences between two (binary) files.
Also you can use the`rdiff` command.

Answer (score -2):

If you still want to use diff & patch. Here is a way...
Write a c program yourself to insert a newline character at the end of every 512/1024/your_choice bytes (this is just to fool the diff as it compares the files line by line). Run this script on your two input files.

Then run 'diff -au file1 file2 > mod.diff (you will get the patch here)'

Patching is simple 'patch < mod.diff'

Than again write a program to remove the newlines from the binary file. That is all...

Comment: Is this binary safe or advisable?