# Searching for a maintained binary diff/patch tool or library

Tags: windows, binary, diff, patch

I am looking for an executable (or a library that I might embed in C# or via Managed C++ into the C# project) to create binary diff files for two folders and their contents and a patch tool to apply those patch files as well targeting Windows.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731035/binary-diff-and-patch-utility-for-a-virtual-machine-image) refers to various tools such as [bsdiff/bspatch](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) which is highly dated. The [3rd party executable that is available here](https://www.pokorra.de/coding/bsdiff.html) does not work when trying it out though. Another variant that is not compatible with the original is the [following](https://github.com/mendsley/bsdiff). Unfortunately it relies on bzlib and certain Linux headers and I wasn't really able to set it up accordingly under Visual Studio.

Anyways, all tools and posts are about 8-10 years old and I'd like to know which tools and libraries are currently maintained that I might take a look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been experimenting with [Octodiff](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff) and I am impressed and will most likely be using it in production.